# Mathematical Application of Project Euler 215 - Crack-free Walls

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, project-euler

I am taking a Math course as part of a Data Science curriculum. For the final project we have to solve a math problem in Python and write it up. I chose [Project Euler 215 Crack-free Walls](https://projecteuler.net/problem=215), my course instructor advised me to look for broader mathematical implications of the solution, but I am drawing a blank on that. I use combinatorics (coin change problem) to form the possible rows and then summing the end position of the bricks to form sets that I then check for disjointedness, thus no cracks. So apart from the considerable programming challenge for a novice I am covering some combinatorics and some set theory. But are there any broader mathematical applications of this problem (or similar) that I can research?

Comment: I have a few ideas for this problem. Firstly represent a row of bricks as a string of $2$'s and $3$'s. There are only six possible combinations(not permutations) for this, because the total number should be $32$. You should create a function $f_r(x)$ which would give the sum of the digits upto upto $(r-1)th$ index. Now you have to compare row 1 with 2, 2 with 3, 3 with 4, and likewise. Now, this function would be called 320 times for each time you compare two rows. And the total number of permutations possible is 6^10*2471.

Comment: Thanks, I actually solved it my question is does this have real world math applications. I assume bricklayers don't whip out Python to calculate their walls :D